# Git: See my last commit

Tags: git

I just want to see the files that were committed in the last commit exactly as I saw the list when I did `git commit`. Unfortunately searching for

```
git "last commit" log
```

in Google gets me nowhere. And

```
git diff HEAD^..HEAD
```

is not what I need, of course, since it spews the guts of the change too.

Comment: Thanks, I actually just needed `git diff HEAD^..HEAD`!

Comment: @Ameen faster to type with `git show -1`

Comment: @Ameen Also `git diff HEAD^ HEAD`

Answer (score 544, accepted):

As determined via comments, it appears that the OP is looking for

```
$ git log --name-status HEAD^..HEAD
```

This is also very close to the output you'd get from `svn status` or `svn log -v`, which many people coming from subversion to git are familiar with.

`--name-status` is the key here; as noted by other folks in this question, you can use `git log -1`, `git show`, and `git diff` to get the same sort of output. Personally, I tend to use `git show <rev>` when looking at individual revisions.

Comment: I admit, comments are not the best way for me to make my question cleaer :)  thanks MikeSep

Comment: I think this gives THE last commit, no?  So, for MY last I would do `git log --stat --author nroose -n 1`

Comment: And can be abbreviated and shortened with                           git show --name-status --oneline

Comment: That's so obvious!  I should've guessed it's something so simple since this is the sort of query that happens all the time.

Comment: In the case of using force push this comand will show you the last patch instead of the latest (timewise) commit ... might be tricky in some use cases

Comment: Shown nothing to me :-(

Comment: just use -1 for the last commit instead of HEAD^...HEAD.

Answer (score 333):

Use [git show](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show.html):

```
git show --summary
```

This will show the names of created or removed files, but not the names of *changed* files. The `git show` command supports a wide variety of output formats that show various types of information about commits.

Comment: @jamessan `git show --stat` is close, but isn't there a view where the word 'modified' or 'added' appears next to the file?

Comment: If you want just the names of the files (even less than `--stat`), you may also want to look at `--name-status` and `--name-only` switches.

Comment: @MikeSep, that's actually what I needed. If you make it an answer I'll mark it best answer, since to me it was. I'm using `git log --name-status HEAD^..HEAD`

Comment: This is by far the simplest solution of the ones offered.

Comment: If you just call `git show`, you will see a diff of your last commit

Answer (score 163):

```
git log -1 --stat
```

could work

Comment: Other solutions seems to output uncommited changes in addition to the last commit, which is not what I want. This seems to output only the commit changes.

Answer (score 74):

By far the simplest command for this is:

```
git show --name-only
```

As it lists *just* the files in the last commit and doesn't give you *the entire guts*

An example of the output being:

```
commit  fkh889hiuhb069e44254b4925d2b580a602
Author: Kylo Ren <Kylo@darkside.empire.gov>
Date:   Sat May 4 16:50:32 2168 -0700

Changed shield frequencies to prevent Millennium Falcon landing

 www/controllers/landing_ba_controller.js             
 www/controllers/landing_b_controller.js            
 www/controllers/landing_bp_controller.js          
 www/controllers/landing_h_controller.js          
 www/controllers/landing_w_controller.js  
 www/htdocs/robots.txt                        
 www/htdocs/templates/shields_FAQ.html
```

Comment: Consider `--name-status` instead of `--name-only`.

Comment: There's the problem right there.. the empire's using php for the defence grid!

Comment: Best example I've seen on stackoverflow!  "Those aren't the commits you're looking for."

Comment: For those coming along after, if you look at the edits made on 2020-01-14, the other comments will make more sense. Well, except the first one, which already made sense.

Comment: If you still want the status but also want the shortened form, consider `git show --oneline --name-status`.

Answer (score 74):

To see the last commit:

```
git log -1
```

To see the last 2 commits:

```
git log -2
```

And so on ....

Comment: But the question said *"...want to see the **files** that were committed in the last commit"*.

Comment: I know this discussion was ages ago, but listen @PeterMortensen if --name-status option added `$ git log -1 --name-status` then it's same as `$ git log --name-status HEAD^..HEAD` suggested by @Mike Seplowitz

Comment: This was perfect for me since in my case, I only wanted to get my hands on the commit hashes and didn't need any of the other info. This only displays is the *commit hash*, *author*, and *date* - starting with the most recent. Nice and succinct.

Answer (score 34):

To see last commit changes

```
git show HEAD
```

Or to see second last commit changes

```
git show HEAD~1
```

And for further just replace '1' in above with the required commit sequence number.

Answer (score 27):

After you do several commits or clone/pull a repository, you might want to see what commits have been made. Just check these simple solutions to see your commit history (from last/recent commit to the first one).

For the last commit, just fire this command: `git log -1`. For more interesting things see below -

1. To see the commit ID (SHA-1 checksum), Author name <mail ID>, Date along with time, and commit message -

   ```
   git log
   ```
2. To see some more stats, such as the names of all the files changed during that commit and number of insertions/deletions. This comes in very handy while reviewing the code -

   ```
   git log --stat
   ```
3. To see commit histories in some pretty formats :) (This is followed by some prebuild options)-

   - If you have too many commits to review, this command will show them in a neat single line:

     ```
     git log --pretty=oneline
     ```
   - To see short, medium, full, or even more details of your commit, use following, respectively -

     ```
     git log --pretty=short
     git log --pretty=medium
     git log --pretty=full
     git log --pretty=fuller
     ```
4. You can even use your own output format using the `format` option -

   ```
   git log --pretty=format:"%an, %ae - %s"
   ```

   where %an - author name, %ae - author email, %s - subject of commit, etc.

This can help you with your commit histories. For more information, click [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History).

Answer (score 23):

```
git log -1 --name-status
```

Does the work for me.

Answer (score 13):

```
$ git diff --name-only HEAD^..HEAD
```

or

```
$ git log --name-only HEAD^..HEAD
```

Comment: That's what I need pretty much. How about something saying whether it was modified, added or deleted? Maybe with a letter, svn-style?

Comment: Got it now. `git log --name-status HEAD^..HEAD`

Comment: Instead of `git log ... HEAD^..HEAD`, isn't it simpler to use `git log ... -1 HEAD`, or better `git show ... HEAD`?

Comment: After browsing through a couple of Stackoverflow posts, this is the answer I need. I only wanted the files and nothing else. No commit summary, just the files from the latest commit. THANKS!

Answer (score 12):

This question is already answered above which states the file names in last commit by git log / other commands. If someone wants to see what all changed in last commit (line differences), you can use this command -

```
git show
```

This automatically displays the line differences in last commit.

Answer (score 6):

`git diff --stat HEAD`

This shows the same diffstat as your last commit.

Answer (score 6):

Like `git log -1 --stat` you can use `git show --stat`.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to list only the files is to use:
`git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD^..HEAD`
Or you can use any two commit IDs

Comment: advantages of this to `log`?

Comment: It is basically a different way of listing the files. I usually combine this with rsync for deployment

Answer (score 4):

To Get my last commit message alone in git

`git log --format=%B -n 1 $(git log -1 --pretty=format:"%h") | cat -`

Answer (score 3):

You can run

```
git show --source
```

it shows the author, Date, the commit's message and the **diff --git**  for all changed files in latest commit.

Answer (score 3):

To see previous Commit SHA

```
git log -n 2 --pretty=format:"%h" | tail -n 1
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to see just the name of files in the last commit

```
git diff HEAD@{1} --name-only
```

if you want also to see the content changes remove the **--name-only**

if you want to compare current state with older commits, increase the **{n}**

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about finding the latest and greatest commit **after you've performed a git checkout of some earlier commit** (*and forgot to write down HEAD's hash prior to executing the checkout*) most of the above won't get you back to where you started. *git log -[some #]* only shows the log from the **CURRENT position of HEAD**, which is not necessarily the very last commit (state of the project). Checkout will disconnect the HEAD and point it to whatever you checked out.

You could view the entire *git reflog*, until reaching the entry referencing the original clone. BTW, this too won't work if any commits were made between the time you cloned the project and when you performed a checkout.  Otherwise you can hope all your commits on your local machine are on the server, and then re-clone the entire project.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it’s a good point but the original question was much simpler and already answered well many times.

Answer (score 0):

and without git: `tail -n1 .git/logs/HEAD | cut -d' ' -f1,8-`

Answer (score 0):

First run below command to get your commitId and copy the commitId of which you want to see the files for.

```
git log
```

Then run,

```
git show <commitId> --name-only
```

In the above command replace  with actual commitid you got from `git log`. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

From `man git-diff`, then typing `/EXAMPLES`:

```bash
 git diff HEAD^ HEAD
```

Compare the version before the last commit and the last commit.

**Comparing with arbitrary commits**

```bash
 git diff test            (1)
 git diff HEAD -- ./test  (2)
```

1. Instead of using the tip of the current branch, compare with the tip of "test" branch.
2. Instead of comparing with the tip of "test" branch, compare with the tip of the current branch, but limit the comparison to the file "test".

**General use**

```bash
 git diff            (1)
 git diff --cached   (2)
 git diff HEAD       (3)
```

1. Changes in the working tree not yet staged for the next commit.
2. Changes between the index and your last commit; what you would be committing if you run "git commit" without "-a" option.
3. Changes in the working tree since your last commit; what you would be committing if you run "git commit -a"