# Unable to find files from a git branch on local copy (clone) of github repo

Tags: git

I have a repo on github on which a branch "strlen" was created. I can go to github.com and select that branch and see my latest commits.

On my local computer I did a clone of that repo. Then did

```
git checkout strlen
```

I can not see the latest commits: instead only the commits in master.

What did I do wrong/what is the next step to see those files that are actually visible on github?

Comment: Please follow the below link for your answer.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231546/git-see-my-last-commit

Comment: @arshpreet Your comment/the suggested link does not answer my question

Comment: @javadba trygit pull origin strlen

Comment: @Socratees  Pls make this an answer. I know, my question was v basic .. but in any case thx for the help - and why not get yourself a few more points.

Comment: @Socratees Well i awarded VonC for a similar answer, but if you put yours down I will still upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need (for your [strlen branch](https://github.com/javadba/spark/commits/strlen)):

```
git fetch origin
git checkout -b strlen origin/strlen
```

If you already had that branch, you can reset it to `origin/strlen`:

```
git checkout strlen
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/strlen
```

---

[Socratees](https://stackoverflow.com/users/931959/socratees) suggestion `git pull origin strlen` would work too considering `strlen` was done on top of `master` (which is the default checked out branch after a clone).

```
 git clone arepo
 git checkout strlen # strlen now refers to the current master
```

Since `git checkout strlen` created a local branch at the same commit as `master`, a `git pull origin strlen` would merge `origin/strlen` to the local `strlen` (like `master`): it would be a fast-forward merge, moving local `strlen` to `origin/strlen`.

Comment: OK, i already followed Socratees' suggestion. I was already on branch strlen - so it seems that git pull origin strlen did the trick. In any case i upvoted your answer. Not sure since i already requested Socratees make his comment an answer who to award.

Comment: @javadba ok, I have included various solution in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @javadba I have added an explanation as to why a `git pull` would have worked in your case. But that wouldn't have worked for any branch in general.

Answer (score 0):

*****You can clone the branch using the command:*****
    git clone path -b branch_name
*****and then can run the command:*****
    git pull/fech                              --> To update with the remote branch
    gIt checkout branch_name    --> To update with branch_name

Comment: Does it answer your question? @javadba